# SEO: Can multiple pages have the same h1?

Tags: seo, h1

I am developing some instructional material in writing HTML & PHP and I am *not* trying to give SEO advice. However, I don’t want to indulge in bad practices or get involved in a fight with an SEO guru.

I understand from what I have read that Google will find its ways through the various headings, which will include lower levels as well, combined with usual `title` element and the keyword & description `meta` elements. That places less emphasis on the `h1` element. I trust the other search engines have a similar attituted.

If each page has adequate `h2` elements, titles and other descriptive elements, is there much of a penalty if the `h1` content is the same?

Comment: My guess is that this is going to depend on context. I'm assuming that your title tags are unique, so what's your use case for having `h1` tags that differ from your titles?

Comment: In this case the `h1` is in the banner and part of the look. The `title` element varies and there is a distinct `h2` element probably doing what the `h1` should be doing. I have the site name in the `h1` and the page name in the `h2`.

Comment: You're right in thinking that the `h2` is doing what the `h1` should be doing, but of course that doesn't really answer your question. My hunch is that Google is smart enough to make sense of your current setup, but perhaps someone else can weigh in on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would only use keywords relevant to the page in the H1 tag. The reasons for this are that it is

a) not very descriptive for the end user if all the pages have the same H1 text regardless of page content (unless the text is hidden) and

b) it will have an impact on your other keyword rankings as you could make better use of the H1 tag to contain keywords which ARE relavant to the page.

The general rule of thumb is that each page should target only 1 or 2 unique, specific keywords or phrases, meaning that all of the on-page optimisation should incorporate these into the various tags and elements, such as the H1.

I don't think Google would give you a massive penalty for this but I know that you could target your keywords much more effectively by not duplicating your H1s across each page.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess... You are using a template? [insert cheese eating grin]

Template designers very typically use the h1 tag for static design elements in the header when they should not too. This is poor design. Headers are often used for styling elements instead of content by designers who do not understand that content elements should never be used for styling. They can be styled of course, but MUST BE content and not just for pretty.

If this is the case, I would convert your h1 to a div with CSS styling and use an h1 at the top of the content. This should be simple to do.

The h1 tag is critically important to search engines. It should be a longer version of your title tag which should be short. This allows you to increase the search value of the title tag with a high degree of importance.

That said, contrary to popular belief, search is NOT about keywords and has not been for a very long time. Page and Brin, Googles founders, railed against term match search engines in their original research paper. Google was designed with linguistic semantics in mind. Granted, originally, semantics use was limited to the term index schema originally used by Google, but changed when rolling in Google Scholar algorithms ending in 2006.

Today, Google makes heavy use of linguistic semantics.

This means that search is about whole language and more topic focused. Sure the use of terms is important, however search is more about semantic topic scores and understanding the content by literally parsing sentences and scoring the content using a series of semantic scoring methods.

This means that content format is important including the use of headers.

Google is still traditional. Why? Because it makes sense to be. Without getting into long boring details, search engines evolve and follow what the content creators do. At no point has tradition left the content creator and therefore Google must pay attention to what the content creators do. And oddly, this has not changed. Why? Because this is how people think. Tradition is a natural form of evolution over decades, centuries, and millennium.

Just to help you out a bit, here is what is seen important roughly in order for weighting semantics.

1. Inbound Links (links to your site)
2. Title Tag
3. H1 Tag
4. Description Meta Tag
5. Navigational Links
6. Internal Links (links within your site)
7. H2 - H6 Tags
8. Content, top to bottom (generally), first and last paragraph, etc.
9. Citations (real citations and not links)

Keep in mind that templated content is ignored for search. This includes headers, footers, and sidebars.

Also keep in mind that the keywords tag is largely and nearly completely useless. So I would recommend chucking it. Why work hard if you do not need to?